# Python:Extract substring from String using Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Trying to extract substring from a string. Working for single record but getting NAN for Multiple Records.

Expected Output:

```
1st Row:HKA-33711-15293045
2nd row:HKA-94612-14661285
```

Code Tried:

```
df1['o_position'] = df1['Event Value'].str.find('HKA-')
df1['o_position_to_18'] = df1['o_position']+18
df1["order_id"]=df1["Event Value"].str.slice(start=df1["o_position"],stop=df1['o_position_to_18'])
df1.head()
```

Data:

```
{'"af_currency"':'"INR"','"af_revenue"':429,'"af_customer_user_id"':'"33738413"','"af_price"':['"399"'],'"af_receipt_id"':'"HKA-33711-15293045"','"af_content_id"':['"72769"'],'"sessionId"':'"-1551484318545"','"af_quantity"':['"1"'],'"af_param_1"':'"HKA-33711-15293045"','"af_content_type"':'"order"'}
```

2nd Row:

```
{'"af_price"':['"2199"'],'"af_content_id"':['"72289"'],'"af_quantity"':['"1"'],'"af_param_1"':'"HKA-94612-14661285"','"af_content_type"':'"order"','"af_currency"':'"INR"','"af_revenue"':2199,'"af_receipt_id"':'"HKA-94612-14661285"'}
```

Comment: The data does not match the column names. Can you show a sample dataframe and expected output?

Comment: @amanb: Removing Column name, I have using below string in single column and have to extract HKA-33711-15293045 from string

Comment: Try `df1[df1['Event Value'].str.contains('HKA-')]` to get a dataframe of all rows which have string in `Event Value` column. One more thing: Get rid of the " " in the dataframe values.

Comment: Thanks @amanb:Want to extract only HKA-33711-15293045

Comment: The use `df1[df1['Event Value'].str.strip().str.match('HKA-33711-15293045')]`. Strip will remove whitespaces from the string.

Comment: @amanb:HKA-33711-15293045 will not same for all rows. It will Start from HKA..

Comment: Use `df1[df1['Event Value'].str.strip().str.lower().str.contains('?=hka*.')]`. This will match all strings that start with hka

Comment: Thanks @amanb: It will give me all columns contains string like hka but i want to store HKA-33711-15293045 in to different column for each row..hope u understand my problem

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your problem. Please show your expected output in the question.

Comment: Why are you using double quotes though?

Comment: @amanb: Updated Question

Comment: @kerwei: Its in data

Comment: So your keys are actually `"af_currency"` and not `af_currency`?

Comment: @kerwei:Yes its in double quotes

Comment: If the row value is NaN, instead of a valid 'HKA` value then you will get NaN only unless you drop the row with `dropna()`